# Different questions about TiStorekit and IAP within Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: in-app-purchase, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, storekit, appcelerator-mobile

I'm struggling heavily over a couple of understanding problems around In-App purchases, auto-renewable subscriptions and handling the receipts. I want to list my questions down here and hope that there's someone outside who can provide some answers or intelligent remarks on these topics. I'm stuck.

**1) What are receipts?**
My understanding was that a receipt is nothing else than an evidence of a successful transaction with Apple, as you get if you buy something in a local supermarket. From an app development perspective I would say, you've to keep the receipt - received when purchase was succcessful - on your servers as well as on the local device. Because you want to verify you bought the related product. Is that correct?

**2) What has to be stored?** 
What exactly should be stored? I'm working with Appcelerator Titanium (latest version) and for an app on iOS 10 - that means I'm also working with the wrapped Storekit-API "TiStorekit" which provides a lot of functionality. Let's say I receive a receipt, how do I access it? There is `evt.receipt` (evt = incoming event) to get receipt informations, but f.e. not the expiration of a subscription, it's not inside there. I can also access `storekit.receiptProperties`, there I'm able to get a list of JSON directives which - I thought - are transactions. It's now possible to find the entry in this list, where the `transactionIdentifier` matches the one from `evt.receipt` - then it seems to be correct and I've my informations together. **BUT IS THAT CORRECT?**

**3) How to validate / verify receipts?** 
There are many functions inside of "TiStorekit" to verify/validate your receipt. When I have to do this and based on which receipt? The one I stored for the user, which should be valid and I have to verify with apple if it's still valid?

**4) `ReceiptProperties` and receipt from `evt`**
As in question 2 mentioned, what's exactly the data available with `storekit.receiptProperties`? And what's the receipt within the event (sent to transactionStateListener) in comparison?

For me this topic is very complicated. Basically there's a lot of documentation at all, most of them directly from native Ojective-C/Swift examples, but somethimes also helpful to understand what you've to do. From a Titanium/Appcelerator perspective it's difficult, there are some examples or code from other people and I can use parts of that, but this implementation is heavily related to the app itself and you shouldn't do that if you don't now what kind of data you're handling and basically WHY.

That's the reason I hope to find answers here. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: A lot of questions, and none are really on-topic for StackOverflow. I recommend asking them on http://tislack.org

Comment: Hi @RenePot , indeed there are a lot of questions. As developer platform is StackOverflow still the right place to ask these questions for the public crowd of developers. I've asked the questions also inside of the #helpme channel in TiSlack and hope for some help also in there.

Comment: Stackoverflow is meant for questions about code. You should also show code what you've tried. Also only ask 1 question per question on stackoverflow